# Downloading files from s3 with wildcard entry

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using a package "[lambduh-get-s3-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambduh-get-s3-object)" to download files from s3 folders. So far it works in a simple way, if you give bucket name and file path, it will download the file for you.

```
 srcBucket: "bukcetname",
 srcKey: bucketpath + filename,
 downloadFilepath: "/tmp/"+filename
```

What I am looking for is wildcard search. for folder and filename. I searched through above packages source code and it doesnt seems to support it. Is there any other known packages to download files like this? any guidance appreciated.

```
 srcBucket: "bucketname",
 srcKey: 'firstfoldername/*/*1111.csv,
 downloadFilepath: "/tmp/"+filename,
```